# New Customer created by Checkout, then create Subscription on Customer results in Error: This customer has no attached payment source

Tags: stripe-payments

New Customer created by Checkout, then create a new Subscription on the same Customer by Node SDK results in `Error: This customer has no attached payment source`.

However if I look at the Customer at the dashboard, there is a Card, but not set as Default.  Once it is "Set as Default" by clicking the `...` it works.

Here is the code I used to create a new Subscription on a Customer:

```
const customer = 'cus_xxxxxx'
const plan = 'plan_xxxxxx' 
stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer,
            items: [
                {
                    plan
                }
            ]
        })
```

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of Checkout since https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout says

> Better support for saving customer details and reusing saved payment methods

Right now my workaround is to use webhook to update Customer's `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` on `payment_method.attached`.

This works but it feels strange. Did I miss something?  Why does Checkout not set the only Card as `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Stripe support:

> Checkout does not currently support the ability to reuse saved payment
>   methods. We are aware that this is a feature request for a lot of our
>   users, and we are working on implementing this in the future.
>
> If you'd like, you can see a roadmap of the updates we'll be making to
>   Checkout in the document below.
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout#checkout-roadmap
>
> That said, the work around you're doing for the moment is the same
>   work around that we're suggesting to users for the time being.

Comment: What is "the workaround that you're using" ?

Comment: "Right now my workaround is to use webhook to update Customer's invoice_settings.default_payment_method on payment_method.attached." see above in the question

Answer (score 2):

This behavior seems intentional on Stripe's part, the card from Checkout is attached to the Customer as a `Payment Method`, and is not set as default.

The same thing happens if you create a Customer directly with a PM,

`let cust = await stripe.customers.create({ payment_method: "pm_card_visa" });`

Also, fwiw, one can create their subscription directly from Checkout, passing a `plan` instead of `sku` https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-redirect-to-checkout

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I realized there is one step that is easy to miss in the docs: take the attached payment method and set it up as a default.

Here is my full server node.js code for creating a subscription:

```
const customerResponse = await stripe.customers.create({ email, name })
const customer = customerResponse.id

await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(paymentMethodId, { customer })

await stripe.customers.update(customer, {
  invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: paymentMethodId }
})

await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer,
  items: [{ price: 'price_XXXXXX' }]
})
```

`paymentMethodId` `name` and `email` come from the client.